# Two return statements on form submit in django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, django-forms

I have django form which displays the check boxes.After selecting the checkboxes user will click submit button which will executes request.POST part of the view.py and returns PDF file. Now after returning the PDF file how can i refresh the the same page?

views.py

```
 if request.POST:
    generate PDF file using reportlab tool
    return PDF
 else:
    return template which consist of django form
```

Now here on request.POST i can get the PDF file, at the same time how can i refresh the page?

After returning the PDF i want to refresh the same page. Any solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Now after returning the PDF file how can i refresh the the same page?" Doesn't make sense.  You can either return the PDF or refresh the same page.  One or the other.  Not both in sequence.

Comment: How about using client scripting?

Comment: Client scripting is  not a Python or Django question. Close this question and ask a Javascript question that **does not mention Python**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments are correct, this has nothing to do with any server-side language, so i'll try to give you directions on how to solve this instead:

A very common solution is that you do not return the PDF directly, but a HTML page that says something like "Your download will begin shortly". This page can use a link or a bit of javascript to open the PDF file in a new browser window. After that the page can remain open or automatically redirect elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The question doesn't make sense.

The user can only see one response at a time. If the response to your form is the PDF, that's what they'll see in their browser.

Comment: How about using client scripting?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can return the PDF and in the same time the background page to refresh or even redirect to something else after a time interval.

You just need put into the HTML header of the generated background page the following code:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="3;URL=http://www.some.org/some.html">
```

which will redirect the user after 3 seconds to the provided URL.

Hope this helps.